# Convert 8 bit sse register to 16 bit shorts

Tags: c, optimization, sse

I have a `__m128i` register with 8 bit values with the content:

```
{-4,10,10,10,10,10,10,-4,-4,10,10,10,10,10,10,-4}
```

Now I want to convert it to eight 16 bit values in a `_m128i` register. It should look like:

```
{-4,10,10,10,10,10,10,-4}
```

How is this possible with the least amount of instructions as possible? 
I want to use SSSE3 at most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you just want the first 8 values out of the 16 and are going to ignore the other 8 (the example data you give is somewhat ambiguous) then you can do it with SSE2 like this:

```
v = _mm_srai_epi16(_mm_unpacklo_epi8(v, v), 8);
```

Comment: works perfect. Is there a more efficient version with SSSE3? Thanks!

Comment: @martins no, none of that helps. In SSE4.1 you'd have `pmovsxbw`, though. For unsigned conversion you could use a single `pshufb`, but, on all (afaik) processors that don't support SSE4.1 that isn't any better than an unpack and a `psrlw` or an unpack and a `pand`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way with one SSE2 instruction (ignoring initialization)

```
__m128i const zero = _mm_setzero_si128(); // (if you're in a loop pull this out)
__m128i       v;

v = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(v, zero);
```

Comment: Note that this method will not work for signed 8-bit integers.

Comment: That is correct, this only works with unsigned 8-bit integers. Good point.